# how to set a handler in web.config with IIS7?

Tags: asp.net

I have a handler, on runtime it create a watermark on images from a specific folder. The problem is that it worked, but now it doesn't.

All that I did was to changed the hosting.

My `web.config` looks like this:

```
<handler>
 <add verb="*" name="ImageWatermarkHandler" type="ImageWatermarkHandler" 
      path="Pics/*.jpg,Pics/*.png"  modules="IsapiModule"
      scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
      resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handler>
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: it's possible that the Hosting provider has locked the use of custom handlers? Check with your provider.

Comment: I believe the element should be `<handlers>`, not `<handler>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under IIS 7, you have to specify custom http handlers and modules under the `configuration/system.webServer/handlers` element of your web.config (unlike older IIS versions, where the element is `configuration/system.web/httpHandlers`).

There's difference between integrated mode (you only need the handlers part) and classic mode(you need both handlers and httpHandlers). For details see the [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx)

Edit: At first I haven't noticed the precondition for integrated mode, could it be that the new hosting runs your app in classic mode?

Comment: I declared in web.config in configuration/system.webServer/handlers and in configuration/system.web/httpHandlers too, but it is still not working.

Answer (score 4):

your config file should look like this,

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="Pics/*.jpg,Pics/*.png" type="ImageWatermarkHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add verb="*" path="Pics/*.jpg,Pics/*.png" name="ImageWatermarkHandler" type="ImageWatermarkHandler"/>
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

for more information,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343.aspx

Comment: @Coderock.net, try this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I think I found the problem. I can't have in path="Pics/*.jpg,Pics/*.png" just path="Pics/*.jpg". Now I have another problem, i can't see the images from Pics, is like I don't have the right to see them. Can you help me please?

Comment: since you map the handler for the images, you canot view images through the browser. your handler should read and serve the images to browser. see this sample, http://cmsnsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-dynamically-resize-images.html

Comment: It should be noted that you can only use comma delimited paths in IIS6, in IIS7 you must use multiple handlers for each path.