# Why doesn't my asp file HttpHandler get called?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic, httphandler

I've created a handler to capture requests for classic asp files:

```xml
<system.webServer>
   <handlers>
       <add name="LegacyAspHandler" verb="*" path="*.asp"
   type="MyNamespace.LegacyAspHandler, MyAssembly" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
   </handlers>
<system.webServer>
```

The handler is never called.  If I request an asp file that exists, IIS serves the page, and if it doesn't exist, serves a 404.  So I think something in IIS must be handling classic asp files before HttpHandlers get invoked, but I can't figure out what it is.

The handler code is just boilerplate:

```vb
Imports System.Web
Public Class GameModuleHandler
    Implements IHttpHandler

    ''' <summary>
    '''  You will need to configure this handler in the Web.config file of your 
    '''  web and register it with IIS before being able to use it. For more information
    '''  see the following link: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=8101007
    ''' </summary>

    #Region "IHttpHandler Members"

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            ' Return false in case your Managed Handler cannot be reused for another request.
            ' Usually this would be false in case you have some state information preserved per request.
            Return True
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        'we never get here
    End Sub

    #End Region
End Class
```

Comment: it serves up the **.asp file**?  you mean the classic asp page?  what does it serve it up as?

Comment: No, I wasn't clear.  I mean that it runs the script and shows whatever the HTML output of the script it.  In other words, it executes the script, but does not call my handler.

Comment: ok, can you paste you handler code, atleast the definition?

Comment: Is that `web.config` structure right? Shouldn't it be contained within `<handlers>`?

Comment: @TMcKeown: Done, but it's totally empty.  It doesn't do anything yet, I was just testing that it was called at all.

Comment: @Lankymart: I don't know.  Should it?  There seem to be all these different modes, depending on IIS, but no clear documentation on when you want to do what.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank What IIS version you using?

Comment: have you gone thru this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343(v=vs.100).ASPX

Comment: @TMcKeown Was just about to post that... Lol

Comment: I have studied that page, but I'm afraid it offers a lot of confusing information, and I'd prefer to keep my configuration in web.config, and not make magic settings in IIS, because then I'll have to replicate those exact changes on half a dozen other servers.

Comment: @Lankymart: You are right, but the typo is in my post, not web.config, where it **is** contained in `handlers`.  I've updated the post to fix this.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank You might find [how to set a handler in web.config with IIS7?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8769633/692942) helpful...maybe something to do with your `preCondition` and the fact that you may need both `<httpHandlers>` and `<handlers>` depending on your mode (classic, integrated etc).

Comment: @Lankymart: I removed the `preCondition`, and made sure that I'm in IIS7 Integrated mode, so my handler config is in the right place.  But it still doesn't work.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank Found this article which looks promising [IIS 7.0, ASP.NET, pipelines, modules, handlers, and preconditions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/08/30/iis-7-0-asp-net-pipelines-modules-handlers-and-preconditions.aspx) - **Note this from the article** `Note that the “integratedMode” and “classicMode” preconditions only apply to handlers, and the “managedHandler” precondition only applies to modules.`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49078/discussion-between-joshua-frank-and-lankymart)

Comment: Your easiest bet is to rewrite .asp files to your handler using IIS rewrite.  If your handler is working with the extension you gave it then rewrite asp to it.